# Is there any way to obtain tickets for the Taj Mahal night viewing without being in Agra?

Tags: tickets, india, sightseeing, architecture, landmarks

I'll be in a group travelling on a tight schedule from Pune via Delhi to Agra and return.

To obtain tickets to view the Taj Mahal by night the official requirement is that the tickets be picked up physically in Agra a day in advance between 10am and 6pm.

Intended travel arrangements would need to be changed to meet this requirement and time able to be spent in Delhi would be reduced.

Is there any way to obtain tickets without fronting physically the day before?

---

I'm joining a group travelling from Pune via Delhi to Agra with the main aim of including viewing the Taj Mahal by night. An email I have received by the group organisers advises as below.  While I'm sure that the time in Agra would be well spent it would be good to be able to retain the original timing.

- The initial plan was to spend Fri and Sat night at Delhi and go to Agra on Sun morning so we can view the Taj Mahal under Full Moon on Sun night. However, the tickets for night viewing need to be picked up physically from Agra a day in advance (i.e.: on Fri). The ticket pickup time is between 10am-6pm, and seeing that they’ll only take 400 people for night viewing, it would be best to pickup the tickets as soon as the ticket counter opens. This means that we’ll have to be in Agra on Sat by 10am instead of Sun! This also means that we won’t be able to see much of Delhi. So we’ll spend most of the time in Agra.

Comment: you can ask any travel agent in Agra. Those people are quiet handy and can make the arrangements on your behalf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, sort of.  Maybe. If you're lucky.

Firstly, because the dates aren't [always right at full moon](http://www.tajmahal.org.uk/night-at-taj.html), they can vary slightly.  As such, the office of the Archeological Survey controls the tickets, the bookings and the tours.

From the [official site](http://asi.nic.in/asi_monu_whs_agratajmahal_night.asp):

> visitors are requested to confirm the dates from the office of the
>   Superintending Archaeologist, Archaeological Survey of India, Agra
>   Circle, 22 The Mall, Agra

So this leaves you with three options.

1. Turn up as required and buy it like anyone else.
2. There's both an email address and a phone number on the official site - consider contacting them and seeing if there's a way to purchase from outside the city - they may well be accommodating.
3. Slightly sketchier - but if you know a local, get them to go on your behalf.  Failing that, contact your accommodation staff, or a travel agent in Agra and see if they'll do it for you, or can suggest a means of accomplishing this.

Good luck, and enjoy - it sounds amazing!

Comment: A travel agent will always be able to get it for you and is the best option.